# When I add a react component to an array, I get an error of "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render." How do I solve this?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I have a simple Next.js React site which currently has an array of stopwatch components with their respective ids.

What's happening is as I add a stopwatch to the array I receive an error saying "Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render."

I am literally adding new components to the page, so yes it makes sense that there are more hooks ... each stopwatch component has its own hooks.

Interesting note, when I remove one of the stopwatch components from the array I receive the opposite error "Error: Rendered fewer hooks than during the previous render."

Here's the code I have:

````
import { useState } from "react";

function Stopwatch({ id, deleteStopwatch }: { id: number, deleteStopwatch: (id: number) => void }) {
    const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState(0);
    const [duration, setDuration] = useState(0);

    function startStopwatch() {
        setStartTime(Date.now);

        setInterval(() => {
            setDuration(Date.now);
        }, 10);
    }

    let displayTime = Math.round((duration - startTime) / 10) / 100;

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Stopwatch</h1>
            <h2>Duration: {displayTime}</h2>

            <button
                onClick={() => startStopwatch()}
            >Start
            </button>

            <button
                onClick={() => { deleteStopwatch(id) }}
            >Delete  
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}

export function StopwatchPage() {
    const [stopwatches, setStopwatches] = useState([{id: 1, Stopwatch},{id: 2, Stopwatch},{id: 3, Stopwatch}]);

    function addStopwatch() {
        if (stopwatches.length !== 0) {
            const newId = stopwatches[stopwatches.length - 1].id + 1;
            const newStopwatch = {id: newId, Stopwatch};
            let newStopwatches = [...stopwatches, newStopwatch];
            setStopwatches(newStopwatches);
            return;
        } else 

        setStopwatches([{id: 1, Stopwatch}]);
    }

    function deleteStopwatch(id: number) {
        const index = stopwatches.findIndex((value) => value.id === id);
        const newStopwatches = [...stopwatches];
        newStopwatches.splice(index, 1);

        setStopwatches(newStopwatches);
    }

    const stopwatchDisplay = stopwatches.map((item) => {
        return (
            <>
                {item.Stopwatch({id:item.id, deleteStopwatch})}
            </>
        )
    });

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={() => addStopwatch()}>Add Stopwatch</button>
            {stopwatchDisplay}
            {stopwatches.toString()}
        </>
    )
}```


I tried changed the code so that the array was just ids and the stopwatch components were generated with a mapping function and then displayed in the StopwatchPage component.

However, it made it so that the times on the stopwatches didn't persist in their positions. As in say I have a stopwatch in the 8th position. If I delete the 7th position, then the stopwatch in the 8th position (time and all) should move down to the 7th. However, it just deleted the 8th position even though the id's persisted.
````